# Magento Event For Returning Visitor

Tags: module, event-observer

I am looking to hook into a event that will tell me when a returning customer visits the site.

I was thinking about hooking into one of the session events, my question is, how would you go about recognizing when a customer returns to the site.

Is there an event that will tell me when a person visits the site, and if that person is a returning customer or a new visitor?

Any thoughts, ideas are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: The customer you mean to say those who have already order once in site, or register user or any visitor of site.. You know what I mean? Actually I do have some thoughts on it but first I need to be very clear about your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of the customer already having a valid cookie when they return to the site (ie. within 7200s by default on Magento), the only other way you would know is if they logged in.

You could add cookie data to the browser's long term storage (modern browsers only).